# Slow internet connection speed compared to other hosts in the same network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, freebsd

My home network consists of an ADSL modem, directly connected to the Internet, and two laptops, connected to the modem using wireless cards. One of the laptops uses Microsoft Windows 7 and the other FreeBSD 10.1-STABLE. I've installed Microsoft Windows 7 on the FreeBSD box using VirtualBox. Both machines use Internet Download Manager 6.22 to download large files from the Internet (in the FreeBSD box, IDM runs under VirtualBox).

The problem is that the download speed differs dramatically in the two hosts: the Windows 7 box is faster about two or three times, and the FreeBSD box suffers poor Internet speed. When the Windows 7 box is downloading a file, it takes a very long time in the FreeBSD box to load a web page. This is tested with different files on different servers, I believe it is something related to my local hosts. I use default setting on ADSL modem, no bandwidth controlling mechanism or any other tricks are implemented in the modem and both hosts.

The download speed is normal on the FreeBSD box, when the Windows 7 box is not downloading.

Comment: One would think the overhead of running in a virtual machine is the issue. Unless the base PC is *extremely* fast, the virtual Win 7 "PC" cannot keep up with the demands of high-speed access.

Comment: maximum possible speed aside, I'd check both QoS & WWM are on, on the router, sounds like one is starving the other of bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using any bandwidth controls then chances are the Win7 box is saturating your downpipe causing packet loss for any other connections.

If your VirtualBox OS is downloading a huge file does your seperate Win7 box have connectivity problems? It should. That would be normal.

If I'm downloading a linux iso and it's actually saturating my Uverse internet, my wife has trouble browsing Reddit. This is normal.

Comment: Would this be a case where router QoS would do the trick?